# My .exe file created with pyinstaller works on Windows 10, but not on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, pyinstaller

When I run my program on windows 7 I get this error:
*Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI91442\python38.dll

'.

No error messages generated.

FormatMessageW: Feil parameter. (Translated: FormatMessageW: Wrong parameter.)

LoadLibrary: PyInstaller: FormatMessageW failed.*

The program converts a video into a text file, which you can play through the terminal. It uses ffmpeg and ffprobe, which I bundle inside the .exe file. The .exe file works great on Windows 10.

Converted to .exe with pyinstaller using:
pyinstaller --onefile --console --icon="icon.ico" --add-data ffmpeg.exe;. --add-data ffprobe.exe;. code.py

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try building the package on a windows 7 machine or a vm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same proplem.

You have to execute pyinstaller with a version of python that suport the Windows-Version of the system that should run the .exe.
Otherwise pyistaller will bundle a python version that insn`t executable on the executing opterating system.

[Here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) you can see the python releases with a comment whether you can use them with win7 or winXP.
Upt do Version 3.4.x python support winXP and upt to 3.8.x win7.

Consider that also your .py-application should be able to run with the older python-version.

Comment: This is genius! Thank you!

Comment: "Otherwise pyistaller will bundle a python version that insn`t executable on the executing opterating system." This kind of removes the purpose of compiling a python program to a executable in first place then. I was trying to "bypass" compability issues with old python versions, by running my file as .exe on older windows versions but I guess that won't work