# My tkinter executable created with pyinstaller works on Windows 10, but not on windows 11

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

As the title says, I have made a `tkinter` GUI frozen with `pyinstaller` that works as intended on Windows 10 machines but won't open on Windows 11.  On a Windows 11 machine it will initiate the program and the home screen pops up briefly before it shuts without explanation.  I am using `debug` with the freezing which doesn't give any clues, and also when run through the command window it doesn't throw any errors/issues.
I assume there is something buried in it to do with Windows 10 vs 11 [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65961343/my-exe-file-created-with-pyinstaller-works-on-windows-10-but-not-on-windows-7) question but haven't found anything.

Comment: please create an [example]

Comment: first run .exe manually in console/terminal (`cmd.exe`) to see full error message. And if this doesn't show any error then maybe you used `try/except` to hide error and now you have no clue. First you should create version without `try/except` to see full errors.

Comment: Python wasn't created to build .exe file and tools like `pyinstaller` sometimes may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries. And often it needs to add them manually to special file `.spec` before creating .exe. But this need any error messages to see which module/library can make problem. You may also use `print()` in code to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.

Comment: thanks for the help and suggestions.  I have run it through the `cmd.exe` and it throws no errors, it just pops up briefly then closes (the software isn't doing anything at the time either). There are no `try/except` in the startup of the program.  I've built the `.spec` file to include some of the trickier libraries the software requires, as thrown initially by the `cmd.exe` window.  Ill try some `print()` statements to see where exactly it gets to and gives any idea on that. Thanks